# Find column name which matches multiple column search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have a simple search query which works just fine

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, $column, $column2 FROM $table WHERE BINARY account_no='{$_SESSION['account']}' AND $column LIKE '$query' OR $column2 LIKE '$query'") or die(mysql_error());

$output_column=column1 or column2 //which column has been matched?
```

However when there is a match on a particulat column i would like to be able to find out which column has been matched.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does something like this work for you? `if ($column == $result[$column1]) echo "Column 1 was matched";`

Comment: Thank you but this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Francisco Presencia, that cant work, because $result is resource, not an array. He has fetch data from $result, using mysql_result or mysql_fetch_assoc (or mysql_fetch_array), see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just edit your query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        id, $column, $column2,
        IF ($column LIKE '$query', 1, 0) AS `column_true`,
        IF ($column2 LIKE '$query', 1, 0) AS `column2_true`
    FROM $table
    WHERE BINARY account_no='{$_SESSION['account']}' AND ($column LIKE '$query' OR $column2 LIKE '$query')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

so you will fetch also another 2 data field.
if column_true = 1, first column condition was true
if column2_true = 1, second column condition was true

if both are 1, the both column and column2 matched your condition.

Btw: you have error in your query, missing ( ) around OR condition

Comment: "you have error in your query"?? Didn't downvote just because it me laugh and was only half of the answer.

Comment: I ment, another error, he is missing ( ) in the condition. And also I added here solution for him. :-)

Comment: I'll be honest i dont fully understand the query like this. How do i access the column_true or column2_true? Do these almost become column names?

Comment: Yes, it will become column names (virtual). You will access them the same way, as you will access other columns (id, $column, $column2). F.e. $column_true = mysql_result($result, 0, 'column_true'); or you can use mysql_fetch_assoc to assoc all selected columns to an array.

Comment: Thank you all works well. The only thing is when there is no match it throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: mysql_result throws error, when there is no record. so before mysql_result check for any records returned: if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { ... }